# help understanding abstract classes: java calendar method getInstance()

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding the concept behind abstract classes.  The definition I'm reading is that they have at least one method which is declared but lack implementation, thus the class can't be instantiated.  The java calendar class is abstract and can't be instantiated using the New operator, however there's a method called getInstance() which returns a calendar object.  How does this work?

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar(); //doesn't work
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //works
```

Comment: Jon's answer is excellent - but here's a quick addition: Abstract classes can never be instantiated. They don't HAVE to contain any abstract methods, and in fact, can and do usually contain lots of methods that actually have code in them. Generally they are marked abstract because they don't provide some piece of functionality, and the expectation is that a subclass will provide that.

Comment: Abstract factory subclasses decide which instance to return

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your help.  After reading your responses, I went back and read the java tutorials again regarding inheritance and static methods, and it's clear to me now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Abstract classes don't *have* to have any abstract methods. That's just how it's usually done.

Now `Calendar.getInstance()` works by *actually* creating an instance of a subclass. You're allowed to call it because it's a static method. The return value refers to an instance of the relevant subclass, but the return type is just `Calendar`, which is fine due to the normal rules of inheritance.

Here's an example of the same sort of approach, but without all the complexities of `Calendar` - the same principles apply:

```
abstract class AbstractParent {
    public static AbstractParent getInstance() {
        // Normally you'd have code to work out which
        // concrete class to actually use
        return new ConcreteChild();
    }

    public abstract void sayHello();
}

class ConcreteChild extends AbstractParent {
    @Override public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from ConcreteChild");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractParent parent = AbstractParent.getInstance();
        parent.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the motivation behind having `Calendar` as an abstract class? Why didn't Java define it like a normal class? Is this some sort of a pattern? Could you tell me what I need to search for to read more on this?

Comment: @Arjun: There are lots of calendar systems, implemented as different concrete classes. Which of those calendar systems would an instance of just `Calendar` use? (There are alternative designs that could have been used, of course, but *that* aspect of the `Calendar` API isn't an unreasonable one. It's a generally horrible API, but not due to the inheritance model.)

Comment: I think I get it now. The normal inheritance model that Java uses most of the times (which, in this case, would be something like `Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar()`) wouldn't be apt here because then the onus would be on the programmer to figure out what calendar the user's system uses locally. Is that right thinking?

Comment: @Arjun: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Calendar` is an abstract class, you cannot create a new instance like that. If you look at the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), find any method with `static Calendar` listed on it and you will find `getInstance()`, so you can do something like this:-

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Now, if you look at the same doc again, look at `Direct Known Subclasses` at the top of the page, the listed class(es) here are the implementation of Calendar... so, in this case, you can use `GregorianCalendar`, like this too:-

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Both works...

Answer (score 1):

Its returning a GregorianCalender.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class CAN implement static methods.

getInstance() is a static method that returns a default concrete implementation of the abstract class.

In this case, I believe it actually returns a GregorianCalendar instance.

Answer (score 1):

The getInstance() method of the Calendar class doesn't return an object of the Calendar class, instead it returns a calendar with the "default timezone and locale" in my case  a GregorianCalendar wich is a subclass of Calendar. :)